# Asana - Get list of Projects that a user has access to?

Tags: asana

I am coding an "Asana Post" program but I need to give the user the option to choose the Project to post the task to.

But obviously, I can't offer the user to post to all projects as they may not be a member of all of them.

The only option that I see in the API is to pull all the projects with their Team IDs and then to pull all the Users for that Team and check if he is a member.

That seems very tedious.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Users can only see projects they have access to. You don't necessarily need to be a member of a project to have access.

Comment: And therefore my question.
Shouldn't there be an API to return all Projects that a User has Acess to.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You should be able to just use paginate through the /projects endpoint with a workspace specified. And you can do this for each workspace if you want all of them. You'll only see the projects a user has access to.

Comment: I guess the problem lies in the fact that I don't know what paginate means

Comment: Please check out the documentation for more information on this: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/pagination